# Insert new row with data computed from other rows

Tags: mysql, insert-query

Suppose I have a MySQL table called MyTable, that looks like this:

```
+----+------+-------+
| Id | Type | Value |
+----+------+-------+
|  0 | A    |     1 |
|  0 | B    |     1 |
|  1 | A    |     2 |
|  1 | B    |     3 |
|  2 | A    |     5 |
|  2 | B    |     8 |
+----+------+-------+
```

And, for each `Id`, I want to insert a new row with type `C` whose `Value` is the sum of the type `A` and `B` values for the rows of the same `Id`. The primary key on this table is `(Id, Type)`, so there's no question of duplication of Id,Type pairs.

I can create the rows I want with this query:

```
SELECT MyTable_A.Id AS Id, 'C' AS Type, (A_Val + B_Val) AS Value FROM 
       (SELECT Id, Value AS A_Val FROM MyTable WHERE Type='A') AS MyTable_A
  JOIN (SELECT Id, Value AS B_Val FROM MyTable WHERE Type='B') AS MyTable_B
    ON MyTable_A.Id = MyTable_B.Id
```

Giving:

```
+----+------+-------+
| Id | Type | Value |
+----+------+-------+
|  0 | C    |     2 |
|  1 | C    |     5 |
|  2 | C    |    13 |
+----+------+-------+
```

But the question is: How do I use this result to insert the generated type-`C` rows into `MyTable`?

Is there a relatively simple way to do this with a query, or do I need to write a stored procedure? And if the latter, guidance would be helpful, as I'm not too well versed in them.

Comment: This will de-normalise your data. Why do you want to do this? What will happen when the A's and B's change? Can someone modify the C's?

Comment: The reason this is required is that while `C` is defined as `A+B`, and all entries in the tables currently have `A` and `B` values, there will be future entries where only `C` is known and where there's no way to determine the breakdown into `A` and `B` components. I realize that this means that I will have to implement external validation logic that ensures that `C = A+B` for insertions and updates on `Id` s where `A` and `B` *are* known.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just append that select (slightly modified as in "you don't need the `as` clauses") onto an insert. For example:

```
insert into MyTable (Id,Type,Value)
    select MyTable_A.Id, 'C', (A_Val + B_Val) from ...
```

assuming that your query is actually correct - I make no evaluation of that :-)

By way of further example,

```
insert into MyTable (Id,Type,Value)
    select Id+1000, 'C', Value from MyTable where Type = 'A'
```

would add the following rows:

```
+------+------+-------+
| Id   | Type | Value |
+------+------+-------+
| 1000 | C    |     1 |
| 1001 | C    |     2 |
| 1002 | C    |     5 |
+------+------+-------+
```

Comment: Excellent! Simple, and even pre-emptively answered my followup question of "what if there are other columns in the table that I want to just take their default values?"

Answer (score 2):

Just add the following line before your select statement:

```
INSERT MyTable (Id, Type, Value)
```